# Java Program Has Linux Methods - Can I Run Junit Test Cases On Them?

Tags: java, linux, junit, automated-tests

I have a java program that does a cleanup of our environment at End-of-Day. As such, one method that I have written in a Util class called UnixUtil.java does execution of running processes on our linux servers and returns a String object if successful or a null object if unable to execute command:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilderSearch = new ProcessBuilder();
String command = "ps -ef|grep -i engservice|grep -v grep|wc -l"

try {
    Process searchProcess = processBuilderSearch.start();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader searchCommanndReader = new BufferedReader(new         InputStreamReader(searchProcess.getInputStream()));

    String lineSearch;
    while((lineSearch=searchCommandReader.readLine())!=null) {
        sb.append(lineSearch);
    }

    return sb.toString();
} catch(Exception e) {
    LOGGER.error("Exception occurred: [{}]", ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
}

return null;
```

I was just wondering how can I write Java test coverage/automated test cases to test such linux commands. Is there a way?

Comment: Where to you pass the command to the ProcessBuilder? Otherwise I would check the return code from executing the process. Check [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/process_getinputstream.htm) for how to call subprocesses.

Comment: Are you sure that command works? I'm pretty sure that command only works in a shell, not when passed directly. You are not checking the return status of the command. You are not checking its standard error stream. This is badly written code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't of course unit test the linux commands, but you can test whether the linux commands got called.
You do that by mocking the ProcessBuilder class (and also passing it in as a parameter to the method, so that you can pass the mock instead).
You then call the verify method from Mockito to ensure that processBuilderSearch.start() got executed once and that searchProcess.getInputStream() also got executed once.
Template:

```
verify(mockObject, times(3))
```